# What is recursive under the number of parameters in the summary of neural netwroks in pytorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network

I am using `summary` method of `torchinfo` package for printing the network summary.

I have defined a subclass of the `nn.Module` as follows

```
import torch
class aNN(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, layers_stack: tuple):
        super(PINN, self).__init__()
        self.model = torch.nn.Sequential(*layers_stack)
        return
    def forward(self, x):
        return self.model(x)
```

Then, I am building the `aNN` model using the following lines prints total number of parameters as 501 (in stead of 921) and also recursive for hidden layer in the summary as shown next to the code.

```
num_inputs, num_outputs = 2, 1
num_units = 20
num_hidden_layers = 2
activation_fun = torch.nn.Tanh()
input_layer = (torch.nn.Linear(num_inputs, num_units), activation_fun,)
hidden_layers = ((torch.nn.Linear(num_units, num_units), activation_fun)) * 2
output_layer = (torch.nn.Linear(num_units, num_outputs),)
nn_model = aNN(input_layer + hidden_layers + output_layer) 
summary(nn_model)



=================================================================
Layer (type:depth-idx)                   Param #
=================================================================
PINN                                     --
├─Sequential: 1-1                        --
│    └─Linear: 2-1                       60
│    └─Tanh: 2-2                         --
│    └─Linear: 2-3                       420
│    └─Tanh: 2-4                         --
│    └─Linear: 2-5                       (recursive)
│    └─Tanh: 2-6                         --
│    └─Linear: 2-7                       21
=================================================================
Total params: 501
Trainable params: 501
Non-trainable params: 0
=================================================================
```

The same approach but explicit addition of hidden layers has resulted correct number of parameters as shown in below

```
num_inputs, num_outputs = 2, 1
num_units = 20
num_hidden_layers = 2
activation_fun = torch.nn.Tanh()
input_layer = (torch.nn.Linear(num_inputs, num_units), activation_fun,)
hidden_layers = ((torch.nn.Linear(num_units, num_units), activation_fun)) + ((torch.nn.Linear(num_units, num_units), activation_fun))
output_layer = (torch.nn.Linear(num_units, num_outputs),)
nn_model = aNN(input_layer + hidden_layers + output_layer) 
summary(nn_model)

=================================================================
Layer (type:depth-idx)                   Param #
=================================================================
PINN                                     --
├─Sequential: 1-1                        --
│    └─Linear: 2-1                       60
│    └─Tanh: 2-2                         --
│    └─Linear: 2-3                       420
│    └─Tanh: 2-4                         --
│    └─Linear: 2-5                       420
│    └─Tanh: 2-6                         --
│    └─Linear: 2-7                       21
=================================================================
Total params: 921
Trainable params: 921
Non-trainable params: 0
=================================================================
```

What was wrong with the first approach? I am interested in the first approach as it more concise and easy to add multiple layers.
Also, what does recursive mean?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `hidden_layers = ((torch.nn.Linear(num_units, num_units), activation_fun)) * 2`, it recreates a pointer to the same Linear and the activation function, so they are executed twice instead of constructed twice.